# Automating "Browse" button event in Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to automate the "Browse" button click from Selenium.

[image]

For this, I have tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dnn_ctr383_View_filename\"]")).click();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Css path")).click();
```

Both gives me `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:` exception.

I have seen [this](http://automationtricks.blogspot.in/2010/09/how-to-click-on-browse-button-in.html) link here where the author suggest to use AutoIT, but in step 2, the script, the author has created is for IE. Can someone please suggest, how I can automate the "Browse" button click in firefox?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you just need to select a file, or something else as well?

Comment: Try to click on the span above.

Comment: First I need to get the selector window opened after I press the "Browse" button. After that, select a file and upload. Select and upload is secendory. Bringing the browse window on click of "Browse" is the first thing

Comment: Can you copy the xpath (full) of the button from the firebug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly send the file path to the id, like so

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr383_View_filename")).sendKeys("C:\\path\\to\\file");
```

The above step is the answer for your first two steps

1. Click on Browse
2. Select a file to upload

For the third step(click upload), looking at the screen capture I do not see any button which says "Upload". So just click "Save" and I assume that your file will successfully get uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that u need to consider here:

1. ***Clicking the browser button:*** Usually handled by an alert or popup, if the driver is not able to find the element by xpath(which u have acquired from firebug or chrome's inspect element) you should consider looking for iframes in the page source. If an element is in a different frame altogether , u need to switch frames in order to find the element like this

   `WebElement frame = driver.findElementById("name_of_iframe");`

   `driver.switchTo().frame(fr);`

now you can find your element using xpath or css selector like u did. Once completed u can move out of the frame by:- `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

2. ***Uploading the file from desktop:*** Since selenium works only on the html in the browser session u invoked from the driver, it can't perform operations on your desktop.Once you are able to click the browser button u can use [Auto it](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)(works only on windows) or [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)(works with mac, linux, windows and even android) to simulate your events based on the position of your upload button.

Hope this helps